# jquery saving data in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save and add on every click data to an array. I tried this

```
var data = [];
var save = [];
s=0;
i=0;

some called function(){
  data[i++] = some result;
  data[i++] = some other result;
}

$('#someelement').click(function(){
save[s++] = data;
console.log(save); // for debugging
i = 0;
data = '';
});
```

The first save works, but after that I just empty arrays added. Any pointers ?

Comment: Append to JavaScript arrays with `.push()`, not by messing with an incrementing index. `data.push('some result')`

Comment: Don't set `data` to an empty string at the end of your click handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn I know it, and a phone call distracted me from removing my stupid comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're replacing the Array with a string.

```
data = '';
```

You should replace it with a new Array instead.

```
data = [];
```

---

Or reuse the `data` Array by adding a shallow copy of `data` to `save`, then clearing `data`.

```
save[s++] = data.slice();

data.length = i = 0;
```

This allows any other code that has a reference to `data` to retain its reference so that it is always viewing the `data` that is being updated.

Comment: Probably don't want to resuse the same array with `data.length = 0`, because then all of the elements of `save` will point to the same (empty) array...

Comment: @nnnnnn: You're right. I lost track of the fact that the `save` array was getting a reference to the `data` array. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try making a copy of the data array:

```
save[s++] = data.slice(0);
```

This way, whatever happens to data array wont affect the save array's items.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add the current contents of data to a single element in save, use [Array.push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp):

```
$('#someelement').click(function(){
    save.push(data);
    console.log(save); // for debugging
    i = 0;
    data = [];
});
```

...or if it's that you want the current values in `data` added to `save`, use [Array.concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp), resetting `data` back to an empty array:

```
$('#someelement').click(function(){
    save = save.concat(data);
    console.log(save); // for debugging
    data = [];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
data[data.length] = <some value>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [] to create new array.

Here is working example:

```
<script>
   var data = [];
   var save = [];
   s=0;
   i=0;

function addRes(){
    data[i++] = 'some result';
    data[i++] = 'some other result';
}

$('#someelement').click(function(){
    addRes();
    save[s++] = data;
    console.log(save); // for debugging
    i = 0;
    data = [];
});
</script>
```